# Custom compare password validator and this [Angular 2,4,5,6]

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I tried creating a compare password validator

```
  comparePassword():{[s:string]:boolean}{
    console.log(this.formGroup);
    const password1 = this.formGroup.value.txtPassword1;
    const password2 = this.formGroup.value.txtPassword2;

    if(password1 === password2){

      return {passwordMismatch:true}
    }
    return null;
  }
```

and when I added this to validators array of the formControl 
I used bind method so that this points to the correct context but it points to global context while in the runtime which results in an error when I am trying to access 
this.formGroup.value.txtPassword1 and this.formGroup.value.txtPassword2
 as this.formGroup is undefined

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { 
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      txtUserName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      txtPassword1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      txtPassword2: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, this.comparePassword.bind(this)])
    });
  }
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  closeModal:EventEmitter<String>;

  closeResult: string;
  isLogin:boolean;


  open(content,option) {
    console.log(option);
    if (option) {

      this.isLogin = option === 'Login' ? true : false;
      console.log(this.isLogin);


    }
    this.modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then((result) => {
     // this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;

    }, (reason) => {
      //this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;

    });
  }

  Submit(){
    console.log(this.formGroup);
   // this.formGroup.reset();
  }

  comparePassword():{[s:string]:boolean}{
    console.log(this.formGroup);
    const password1 = this.formGroup.value.txtPassword1;
    const password2 = this.formGroup.value.txtPassword2;

    if(password1 === password2){

      return {passwordMismatch:true}
    }
    return null;
  }


}
```

Why is this pointing to global context even after using bind method

what is very difficult for me to understand is the fact that 
when I console the value of this from inside the validator it has the formControl inside it but attaching screenshot
[image]

but when I parsed the object properties through for in everything was listed even the properties in the prototype chain but not the formGroup

The weirdest thing is that, when I console the this it actually has formGroup inside of it and but if I try to access it using this.formGroup it gives me undefined instead

Can anyone explain this I think it would be a simple approach if i could find answer for this as it has the potential to help lot of people looking for simple password comparison

Comment: One thing to remember: when logging an object to the console, you get a reference to the object. When you click on the down arrow, the properties are shown as they are at that moment, not as they were when `console.log` was called.

Comment: It seems that at the moment you are binding to `this`, the `formGroup` is not yet fully initialized (hence it is _undefined_). If you move `comparePassword` validation to `ngOnInit` it should work properly. In _ngOnInit_:
`this.formGroup.get('txtPassword2').setValidators(this.comparePassword.bind(this));`

Comment: @ConnorsFan thanks for pointing it out thats a valuable thing to understand

Comment: @miselking that worked like a charm post it as answer it would be useful for a lot of people and if there is a more elegant way to work with it please point it out .

Comment: @SachinDivakar I have added an answer. I am not aware of any better solution, but I will investigate this further and if I come up with anything, I will _edit_ my answer to include additional details.

Comment: @miselking I found another issue while trying to work with it as you have seen there is empty check validator and to distinguish between the error generated by the two validators on same control I used another approach of getting formGroup.get('txtPassword2').errors['passwordmismatch'] which returns true and error message is added but when the situation happens when password matches again errors become null and error is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at the moment you are binding to `this`, the *formGroup* is not yet fully initialized (hence it is *undefined*).

If you move `comparePassword` validation to *ngOnInit* it should work properly.

Something like this:

```
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { 
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      txtUserName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      txtPassword1: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      txtPassword2: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.formGroup.get('txtPassword2').setValidators(this.comparePassword.bind(this));
  }
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scwnyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

It's expected that the Custom validator would be called at least twice:

1. when the `FormControl` is created (so its status is correct in
   relation to its initial value)
2. when the `FormControlName` directive is created (so the status can be
   updated if there are validator directives defined in the template).
   *When they are invoked in the beginning value is not set yet that's why it is undefined*

I would suggest you go for some sort of guard and I would extract `FormControl` Value in the following way

**Modified Code**

```
   comparePassword(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: boolean } {
     if (control.parent){//
    const password1 = control.parent.value['password1'];
    const password2 = control.value;
      if(password1 === password2){
         return {passwordMismatch:true}
         }
     }
    return null;
  }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactiveformvali-x1voxc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: I wanted to work without formControl that is the reason for all this mess. so then method you are saying is access the other text box indirectly that is a clean alternative